# Как вставить видео с youtube без звука?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/O0MjFnNu4Eg?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Копия вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868226/how-do-you-mute-an-embedded-youtube-player

Вот код оттуда

Нужно включить `&enablejsapi=1` в url, а потом выключить с помощью JS. Сам Youtube не позволяет выключить звук.

HTML:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/O0MjFnNu4Eg?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

JS:

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.mute();
    player.playVideo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Код для вставики через ифрейм взял на сайте:
[девелоп.гугл](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo?hl=ru)

Получился такой код с айди и необходимыми настройками:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="425" height="235" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/****************?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&controls=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&iv_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

А js честно взял на странице: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BFDKS/966/)

```
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady() {
        player.playVideo();
        // Mute!
        player.mute();
    }
```

Теперь все работает)

всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы отключить звук в iframe видео достаточно добавить параметр mute=1

Answer (score 0):

O0MjFnNu4Eg?autoplay=1&mute=1
и никаких js не надо

Comment: а что нового привносит ваш ответ, в сравнении с теми, что уже имеются?